# Outlook code stopped working

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a 1-min delay on all emails and want to assign a category set up as an exception to the rule to send immediately.

I created the macro but it stopped working.

```
Public Sub CategoriesButton()
   Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
   Set Item = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
   Item.Categories = "SendMe"
   Item.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting - I just had the same issue. Working perfectly but then I restarted Outlook and it stopped working - for no apparent reason.

Took me a while to work this out - but when you restart Outlook it applies Macro security permissions to your macro.

If you haven't digitally signed your macro, the default behaviour is to prevent it from running.

You can relax the security settings so that Outlook with either ask your permission to run macros, or just run all macros regardless (this latter option is probably not a good idea!)

You can self-sign your own macro, there's quite a good guide to doing that here: http://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-use-outlooks-vba-editor/

But annoyingly it seems you will *always* get a notification, even with a signed macro... so it's probably easier to just change the security settings to 'notification for all'.

Hope this helps - the code you posted certainly helped me, it was *exactly* what I was looking for, also to control 1 minute delay!

Man, every time I go near macros in Outlook I end up losing half a day or so...